# How can I find the procedure of the following Nonlinear First Order Ordinary Differential Equation analytically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm try to do this equation, I know about the the "varible change" of the form $\frac{dy}{dx}=P$ for solve this kind of equations but I don't feel this is helpful in solving it, how can I proceed? Some clue?

The equations is:

$$\cos^{2}(xy')-2\cos(y)\cos(xy)=-3\cos(x)$$

Thanks!

[Edit for context]: This exercise comes from an exam that a friend did a long time ago, he was asked to solve the equation analytically. I asked him if the differential is inside the cosine function (Speaking of y'), to which he answered yes, he even "found" the sheet where he did the exercise, however, he does not remember how he did it and it is also very summarized , I do not understand what he did, I will put the image. That's the context of the problem.
(P.S. Cte means Constant)
[image: Cte means constant]

Comment: To know what kind of suggestions make sense, can you give some context of where this equation came from, and what you've tried so far to solve it?

Comment: Could it possible by a typo? $\cos^2(x)\cdot y' -2\cos y \cos x \cdot y=-3\cos x$ looks more like a question.

Comment: @AbelWong You are most likely right, because I have tried to solve it using trigonometric identities but without success, I was told that the differential was inside, which makes the resolution quite complicated, I've edited the question with "the solution" but idk

Comment: @ConMan I've edited the question and put "the solution" I've found for the problem, but I don't understand what happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strongly looks like something has gotten lost in translation (not into English, but from the original exercise to the written answer. Notice that if we try to differentiate $\cos^2(xy)$ then we get:

$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{d}{dx} \cos^2(xy) & = & -2 \sin(xy) \frac{d}{dx}(xy) \\
& = & -2 \sin(xy) (xy' + y)\end{eqnarray}$

and if we differentiate $\cos^2(x) y$ we get:

$\frac{d}{dx} (\cos^2(x) y) = y' \cos^2(x) - 2 \sin(x) \cos(x) y$

In both cases the $y'$ winds up outside the cosine, but also in neither case do we get what was written for the first line.

Answer (score 1):

It is separable:

$(cosx)y'=2(cosy)y-3$

$\frac{dy}{2(cosy)y-3}=(secx)dx$

RHS is integrable. But LHS seems not. I stop here for you to try. If you want, I can continue the steps later.